# 'predict.pca' is not an exported object from 'namespace:mdatools'

Tags: r, pca, prediction

I am kinda new in the R environment, and I am a beginner in programming. I've been using mdatools package to perform PCA analysis and predictions with this model, but I keep getting this error when trying to use predict function.

`Error: 'predict.pca' is not an exported object from 'namespace:mdatools'`

I already looked for "??predict.pca" to check if the function has been moved to another package, but it doesn't look like.

I truly appreciate any suggestions on how to fix this error.

Thank you.

---

This is part of code:

```
library(dplyr)
library(mdatools)
library(pca3d)

pca_trainset = trainset %>% select( -class )
pca_testset = testset
pca_car = pca( pca_trainset, scale = T )

str(pca_car) 

plot(pca_car,show.labels = T)

train = data.frame( class = trainset$class, pca_car$calres$scores )
t = as.data.frame( mdatools::predict.pca( pca_car, pca_testset ) )
```

Comment: Hi Ian. Yes, I've tried to load the package at first, but it is still not working. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

If we look carefully at the help for `help(predict.pca)`:

```
predict.pca {mdatools}
PCA predictions
Description
Applies PCA model to a new data set.

Usage
## S3 method for class 'pca'
predict(object, x, ...)
Arguments
object  a PCA model (object of class pca).

x   data values (matrix or data frame).

... other arguments.
```

We will note that `predict.pca` is not a `function`, but rather an S3 `method` for `predict` on objects of class `pca`. Therefore, the appropriate way to use is with `predict()`.

```
t = as.data.frame( predict( pca_car, pca_testset ) )
```

See [here](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/S3.html) for more.